# IBM data studio not connecting to local DB2 databases

Tags: db2, db2-luw, ibm-data-studio

I have installed DB2 10.5 version on my local Ubuntu 12.04 Machine. Now i need a GUI. I already tried squirrel-sql & Db-Visualizer. While Db-Visualizer give me the view-only database structure, squirrel-sql give me some more options to manage. But now I need a DB2 administrator tool, which can handle all this tasks plus backup/restore, import/export etc.

I have listen a lot for IBM Data Studio as de-facto tool for DB2. So I installed it. After install completion, I am unable connect to my DB2 databases/schemas. It is surprise As I am easily can connect my Dbs through squirrel-sql & Db-Visualizer but IBM Data Studio refuse to connect. It give following errors during try.

```
Full message content: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.17.30] Exception java.net.SocketException: Error opening socket to server localhost/127.0.0.1 on port 50,000 with message: Malformed reply from SOCKS server.

An attempt was made to access a database that was not found, has not been started, or does not support transactions.

Ensure that the specified database name exists in the system database directory. If the database name does not exist in the system database directory, either the database does not exist or the database name has not been cataloged. If needed, issue a db2start command and then resubmit the current command. SQL4499N A fatal error occurred that resulted in a disconnect from the data source. SQLSTATE: 08004
```

I have specified,

```
Local : Db2 for Linux, Unix & Windows
Database : <mydbname>
Host : localhost
Port Number : 50000
UserName : db2inst1
Password : XXXXXX
Default Schema : db2inst1
```

Anybody can suggest if extra steps needed to connect.

UPDATE : Pastebin Link for Stack Trace : http://pastebin.com/ySmrFKNV

UPDATE 1 : Search online for DB2 forums for same problem, Somebody suggested to check system proxy settings. So yes, My system have proxy settings enabled. But even after set proxy to NONE in Netwrok Settings in Ubuntu, problem still persists.

UPDATE 2 : Issue resolved after reinstallation of Data Studio. No idea what problem came, But now it working with same settings.

Comment: Are you sure you can connect to database from db2clp? db2 connect to XXXX. It looks like the instance is not started: db2start

Comment: @AngocA For shell DB Login, I always user login into db2inst1 and pass command 'db2', Which leads me to DB shell, Then I can use command 'connect to <DBName>' to connect db. That is way I use to connect to DB on shell. If db2 command is same as db2clp. I am using DB2 10.5 Linux Version.

Comment: What about the instance port? is it open? test that with 'telnet hostname/IP portNumber'

Comment: It is connected through telnet. As I mentioned in Post, I am able to connect through DB Visualizer & Squirrel Sql tool, where I specified similar settings to connect.

Comment: That is weird. Try to create a PMR

Comment: Can you try to use 127.0.0.1 as localhost?

Comment: @RamazanPOLAT, Tried but results are same, not connecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a answer. But issue resolved after re-installation of Data Studio. No idea what problem came, But now it working with same settings.